# How to get the string based on the 2nd occurrence of a pattern or value?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

If I have a value like this

```
 Name varchar(255) = 'A fox Jumped/ in to the water/ and fought with crocodile/ and then went back/ to jungle and slept'
```

I would like to extract the values using '/' as my delimiter. I could figure out how to extract this part ***'to jungle and slept'***, but I would like to get the 2nd last value ***'and then went back'*** and also the whole part after '/' ***"and then went back/ to jungle and slept"***

```
 Expected values: 

 1. 'and then went back'
 2. 'and then went back/ to jungle and slept'
```

Comment: The easy way is to split the string and then get the "nth" row from the table returned. Note you need a string splitting function that returns a table with two columns - one for the index and one for the item, like [Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of `reverse`,`substring` and `charindex` in conjunction with `cross apply`. Find out the first, second (and upto nth occurrence) occurrence of the character using a series of `cross apply`s and then extract the required substring.

```
select  
 reverse(substring(reverse(str), p1.pos+1, p2.pos-p1.pos-1)) as between_first_sec_from_last
,reverse(substring(reverse(str), 1, p2.pos- 1)) as upto_second_from_last
from (select 'A fox Jumped/ in to the water/ and fought with crocodile/ and then went back/ to jungle and slept' as str) t
  cross apply (select (charindex('/', reverse(str)))) as p1(pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('/', reverse(str), p1.pos+1))) as p2(pos)
```